# How to split a string which is separated by an Element in PHP

Tags: php

I have a variable containing Date and Time Which has been separated by  the element " T "

```
$date_time="2013-05-05T18:30:00";
```

Now I want the date in one variable and Time in another variable like below.

```
$date="2013-05-05";
$time="18:30"
```

Comment: People are falling over one another to tell you how to split the string, but someone should tell you that perhaps it's not a good idea to split it after all. If you want to do *any* manipulation after splitting it, it's better to construct a `DateTime` instance instead and work with that.

Comment: @jon you are right. I want to do some manipulations after splitting it. And that is what juco said..:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are simply trying to split it, then you can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) along with [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
list($date, $time) = explode('T', $date_time);
echo "Date: $date Time: $time";
```

You may also want to look in to PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class if you're looking to do any processing with this.

Comment: @juco, Interesting .. never knew that. +1

Comment: +1 BTW you should use `@` operator (before `list`), because if it does not contain any `T` it will issue a notice. And you should use `2` as the third parameter of `explode`, in case of the string contains more than 1 `T`

Comment: @pozs: Actually instead of the `@` operator it would be IMO better to do `list($x, $y) = array_pad(explode(...), 2, null)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$date_time="2013-05-05T18:30:00";
$dateArr = explode("T",$date_time);
$date = $dateArr[0];
$time =  $dateArr[1];
```

Or save lines of code by just,

```
list($date, $time) = explode("T",$date_time,2);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CVFUoK)**.

Comment: `list($date, $time) = explode(...)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use explode()

Code:

```
$date_time="2013-05-05T18:30:00";

$explodedArray=explode('T',$date_time);

echo $explodedArray[0];
echo $explodedArray[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** function

```
<?php
$date_time="2013-05-05T18:30:00";

$newdate_time=explode("T",$date_time);
echo $newdate_time[0];
echo $newdate_time[1];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need the explode() function. explode('T', $date_time) will give you the array:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(10) "2013-05-05"
  [1] =>
  string(8) "18:30:00"
}
```

if you're sure that the format is always right you can use the more convenient way

```
list($date, $time) = explode( 'T', $date_time )
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing it would be to create 2 new variables for date and time like this:

```
<?php
$timecode = strtotime("2013-05-05T18:30:00");
$date = date("Y-m-d", $timecode);
$time = date("H:i:s", $timecode);
echo "$date $time";
?>
```

This might be advantageous if you want to do further time manipulations in your program.